# spawn-fcgi + multiwatch + nginx + ruby: workers don't respond

Tags: nginx, spawn-fcgi

I've made a website with Ruby and FastCGI, and it works great under Apache.
I'd like to switch to nginx, but I can't get it working.

The website is made of two processes: one takes care of AJAX calls, the other takes care of the rest.

So far I figured out I should use spawn-fcgi to start my workers and bind them to a socket.
Because I'd like to have multiple workers, I also use multiwatch.

The problem is, whenever I try to access to a page, I get a 502 error, and the following line in error.log:

```
2013/04/03 23:58:39 [error] 1450#0: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: v2.localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/fastcgi/site-v2.main.sock:/", host: "v2.localhost:8000"
```

So no worker ever answer the request. `netstat -x` doesn't display the socket at all, but it seems like it's in use, because if I try to launch my start script twice it says `spawn-fcgi: socket is already in use, can't spawn`.

One last thing: if I launch my start script and doesn't try to request a page, the multiwatch processes and the workers terminate properly with one `kill` to multiwatch. But if I request a page, the multiwatch supposed to send the response and *all* its children workers sort of hang. I have to `kill -9` them all.

The site's entry points look like this:

```
require 'fcgi'

FCGI.each do |req|
    process req
end
```

My startup script:

```
USER=www-site-v2
GROUP=www-site-v2

SOCK_MODE=0660

NB_WORKERS_MAIN=4
NB_WORKERS_AJAX=4

MULTIWATCH_BIN=/usr/bin/multiwatch

APP_MAIN=/var/www/site-v2/www/main.rb
APP_AJAX=/var/www/site-v2/www/ajax.rb

PID_MAIN=/run/fastcgi/site-v2.main.pid
PID_AJAX=/run/fastcgi/site-v2.ajax.pid

SOCK_MAIN=/run/fastcgi/site-v2.main.sock
SOCK_AJAX=/run/fastcgi/site-v2.ajax.sock

SPAWN_BIN=/usr/bin/spawn-fcgi
SPAWN_ARGS="-u $USER -g $GROUP -M $SOCK_MODE -d /var/www/site-v2/www"
SPAWN_ARGS_MAIN="-s $SOCK_MAIN -P $PID_MAIN"
SPAWN_ARGS_AJAX="-s $SOCK_AJAX -P $PID_AJAX"

case "$1" in
    start)
        test \! -d /run/fastcgi && mkdir /run/fastcgi

        $SPAWN_BIN $SPAWN_ARGS $SPAWN_ARGS_MAIN -- $MULTIWATCH_BIN -f $NB_WORKERS_MAIN -- $APP_MAIN && \
        $SPAWN_BIN $SPAWN_ARGS $SPAWN_ARGS_AJAX -- $MULTIWATCH_BIN -f $NB_WORKERS_AJAX -- $APP_AJAX
        ;;
    stop)
        test -f $PID_MAIN && kill `cat $PID_MAIN`
        test -f $PID_AJAX && kill `cat $PID_AJAX`
esac
```

My nginx configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name v2.localhost;

    location ^~ /theme/      { root /var/www/site-v2/www/static; }
    location ^~ /javascript/ { root /var/www/site-v2/www/static; }
    location ^~ /avatars/    { root /var/www/site-v2/www/static; }

    location / {
        include fastcgi_params;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/fastcgi/site-v2.main.sock:;
    }

    location /ajax/ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/fastcgi/site-v2.ajax.sock:;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm dumb. For whatever reason, I used `proxy_pass` instead of `fastcgi_pass` in my nginx configuration file. So nginx used the wrong protocol, the workers went "wtf?" and hung.

Works like a charm now.

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name v2.localhost;

    location ^~ /theme/      { root /var/www/site-v2/www/static; }
    location ^~ /javascript/ { root /var/www/site-v2/www/static; }
    location ^~ /avatars/    { root /var/www/site-v2/www/static; }

    location / {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/fastcgi/site-v2.main.sock;
    }

    location /ajax/ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/fastcgi/site-v2.ajax.sock;
    }
}
```